# .net OutputCache. How can i queue requests when cache expires?

Tags: .net, caching

I have a Service Method with a 10 second output cache.

All works as expected, but if i hit the method with multiple requests at the moment the cache expires then all of those requests get uncached responses, and can cause SQL DB problems as as requests hit the database.

Can i queue these requests?